# Webcam virtual background BodyPix problems on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, bodypix

I’m working on a webapp that use the webcam to replace the user background as a virtual background, the problem is it isnt working on ipphone. I have found a lot of documentation and info on how to do it with TensorFlow and BodyPix, I achieved the goal really fast but when I tested on iPhone it doesn't work, so I went and look for tutorials and test several tutorials about this, using different methods. No one of them work properly on iPhone.

I also found BodyPix demos that do work in iPhone (using segmentation masks) so I'm confused about why the issue come when is used to replace the background. I cant find any info. Maybe i do not know how or where to search

Here is one of the bests codes I found, i saved it on a CodePen, This works on PC, Mac, Android, but when I try on iPhone it just wont work.

https://codepen.io/monclee/pen/gOqQNRR

```
// Initialize variables
        let isVirtual = false;

        // DOM elements
        const videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer');
        const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');
        const canvasElement = document.getElementById('backgroundCanvas');
        const backgroundImage = document.getElementById('yourBackgroundImage');
        const ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
        const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
        const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
        const errorText = document.getElementById('errorText');

         // MobileNetV1 or ResNet50
        const BodyPixModel = 'MobileNetV1';

        async function startWebCamStream() {
            try {
                // Start the webcam stream
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
                videoElement.srcObject = stream;

                // Wait for the video to play
                await videoElement.play();
            } catch (error) {
                displayError(error)
            }
        }

        // Function to start the virtual background
        async function startVirtualBackground() {
            try {
                // Set canvas dimensions to match video dimensions
                canvasElement.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
                canvasElement.height = videoElement.videoHeight;

                // Load the BodyPix model: 
                let net = null;

                switch (BodyPixModel) {
                    case 'MobileNetV1':
                        /*
                            This is a lightweight architecture that is suitable for real-time applications and has lower computational requirements. 
                            It provides good performance for most use cases.
                        */
                        net = await bodyPix.load({
                            architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
                            outputStride: 16, // Output stride (16 or 32). 16 is faster, 32 is more accurate.
                            multiplier: 0.75, // The model's depth multiplier. Options: 0.50, 0.75, or 1.0.
                            quantBytes: 2, // The number of bytes to use for quantization (4 or 2).
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'ResNet50':
                        /*
                            This is a deeper and more accurate architecture compared to MobileNetV1. 
                            It may provide better segmentation accuracy, but it requires more computational resources and can be slower.
                        */
                        net = await bodyPix.load({
                            architecture: 'ResNet50',
                            outputStride: 16, // Output stride (16 or 32). 16 is faster, 32 is more accurate.
                            quantBytes: 4, // The number of bytes to use for quantization (4 or 2).
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                // Start the virtual background loop
                isVirtual = true;
                videoElement.hidden = true;
                canvasElement.hidden = false;
                display(canvasElement, 'block');

                // Show the stop button and hide the start button
                startButton.style.display = 'none';
                stopButton.style.display = 'block';

                async function updateCanvas() {
                    if (isVirtual) {
                        // 1. Segmentation Calculation
                        const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson(videoElement, {
                            flipHorizontal: false, // Whether to flip the input video horizontally
                            internalResolution: 'medium', // The resolution for internal processing (options: 'low', 'medium', 'high')
                            segmentationThreshold: 0.7, // Segmentation confidence threshold (0.0 - 1.0)
                            maxDetections: 10, // Maximum number of detections to return
                            scoreThreshold: 0.2, // Confidence score threshold for detections (0.0 - 1.0)
                            nmsRadius: 20, // Non-Maximum Suppression (NMS) radius for de-duplication
                            minKeypointScore: 0.3, // Minimum keypoint detection score (0.0 - 1.0)
                            refineSteps: 10, // Number of refinement steps for segmentation
                        });

                        // 2. Creating a Background Mask
                        const background = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0 };
                        const mask = bodyPix.toMask(segmentation, background, { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 255 });

                        if (mask) {
                            ctx.putImageData(mask, 0, 0);
                            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

                            // 3. Drawing the Background
                            if (backgroundImage.complete) {
                                ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
                            } else {
                                // If the image is not loaded yet, wait for it to load and then draw
                                backgroundImage.onload = () => {
                                    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
                                };
                            }

                            // Draw the mask (segmentation)
                            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
                            ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
                            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

                            // Add a delay to control the frame rate (adjust as needed) less CPU intensive
                            // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

                            // Continue updating the canvas
                            requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Start update canvas
                updateCanvas();
            } catch (error) {
                stopVirtualBackground();
                displayError(error);
            }
        }

        // Function to stop the virtual background
        function stopVirtualBackground() {
            isVirtual = false;
            videoElement.hidden = false;
            canvasElement.hidden = true;
            display(canvasElement, 'none');

            // Hide the stop button and show the start button
            startButton.style.display = 'block';
            stopButton.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Helper function to set the display style of an element
        function display(element, style) {
            element.style.display = style;
        }

        // Helper function to display errors
        function displayError(error){
            console.error(error);
            // Display error message in the <p> element
            errorText.textContent = 'An error occurred: ' + error.message;
        }

        // Add click event listeners to the buttons
        startButton.addEventListener('click', startVirtualBackground);
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopVirtualBackground);

        // Start video stream
        startWebCamStream();
```

As far as I can see there are no errors, also I have tried Chrome and Safari in the iPhone, but is not working at all.

Is this error documented and I haven't found it? Can anyone point me on the right direction, thanks in advance.